# Do Windows 8 Store apps have a MessageBox equivalent?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Do Windows 8 Store apps have something like a MessageBox?

I need something like a popup window to show the user e.g. when a input is wrong or a error happened. Is there something already in the API or do I have to make my own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the [MessageDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog)

Comment: What I see here is that MessageDialog is only supported on Windows Phone 8.1. Is there an 8.0 equivalent?

Answer (score 16):

Modern UI guidelines sugest inline error messages for input. However, if you still want a MessageBox, you can have it in the MessageDialog.

```
 MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Message"); await dlg.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Note the `; await`. I tried `await (new MessageDialog("msg")).ShowAsync()`, but it seems the `await` keyword needs to call the method at an already created object.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have to bypass MessageDialog's limitation on the number of possible commands (three), this [MessageBox implementation](http://blog.instance-factory.com/?p=898) might be helpful.