# How do I show a messagebox in Windows 8/RT xaml?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Windows 8 Store apps have a MessageBox equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903494/do-windows-8-store-apps-have-a-messagebox-equivalent)

Is there an equivalent to this code:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Text","Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = MessageBoxButton.No Then
   Blah()
End If
```

I've searched high and low for something simiar with no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) class can achieve this.