# BitmapImage not loading with correct reference and .dll

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm attempting to us BitmapImage in my Windows Phone 8.1 Pivot App, but cannot get it to work using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; With the correct .dll

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image]

Any advice would be great, cheers.

ps. Tried rebuilds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly want to use [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243235), not `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`.

The former is part of the Windows Runtime API for Windows Store or Windows Phone Apps, whereas the latter is WPF. You can't use WPF in a Windows Store or Windows Phone App.

Comment: Thank you, relatively new to windows phone development. This really helped.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with MessageBox, no idea why they are so different. After much Google searching I can only find the WPF references. Any idea on this one, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I googled "windows store message box": http://stackoverflow.com/q/13903494/1136211